# angular2 access dependency in click function

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services

I am building an app using angular2/Typescript, and attempting to access a service injected as a dependency. In Angular 1.x, I would have accessed this service through the controller function, and all child functions would have been able to access the same dependency.  Here, I am injecting it through the constructor of my component as follows:

```
   constructor( @Inject(JRummy) rummyGame: JRummy) {

        this.currentGame = new Game();
        rummyGame.startGame(this.currentGame);

    }
```

where rummyGame is the service I am attempting to inject. This is working correctly. However, after I have accessed this service within the constructor, how do I access it in other functions? For example, I have the following click function within the component, where I want to call a method in the rummyGame service:

```
  simulateComputer():void {

        rummyGame.computerPlaySolo();

    }
```

how does the rummyGame service get injected into this click function if it was just injected into the constructor? Do I need to create a property on the component to store the instance of that service after it has been accessed by the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shorter way would be do declare variable as `private` so that it will be available in context(`this`) of class directly.

```
constructor( @Inject(JRummy) private rummyGame: JRummy) {

   //code here

}
//do access service object by having this.rummyGame
simulateComputer():void {
    this.rummyGame.computerPlaySolo();
}
```

---

Other thing is you need to have `@Injectable` decorator over you service class to make it `injectable` inside other component constructor as a dependency.

Comment: I tried this -the call to   rummyGame.computerPlaySolo(); works correctly in the constructor with the signature  constructor( @Inject(JRummy) private rummyGame: JRummy), however if i add the same method call in the simulateComputer function,I got the error:ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: l_context.computerPlaySolo is not a function
angular2.dev.js:22367 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
angular2.dev.js:22367 TypeError: l_context.computerPlaySolo is not a function
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_AppComponent_comp_0.handleEventInternal`

Answer (score 1):

Discoved the issue -- The response from Pankaj is correct, but I didn't add the @Injectable() decorator onto the the rummyGame.computerPlaySolo() method in the service itself.  It seems that when the method was called directly from the constructor using  @Inject declaration in the constructor signature, it worked without the @Injectable() decorator, but when I attempted to access it in the click function, it couldn't access the function without the @Injectable declaration